# Is there in Objective-c any custom Date class like DateTime in C# or in any other language

Tags: objective-c, ios, date

Now I am using `NSDate`, `NSCalendar`, `NSDateComponents` and `NSDateFormatter` for very simple tasks, but it's VERY VERY overcomplicated and inflexible stuff ..

So I'm looking for some custom class what implements Date, like in C# or Ruby or Python or PHP or Boost or any other language or framework. Thanks!

UPD:
Thanks, I know how to use `NSDate` and related classes, the question is whether there is a custom class for Objective-C that implements same functionality in more clear way. Maybe like DateTime from C# or Date from Ruby for example that are very useful classes. I would like to see access to components of date, month, days and other with correctly modifying them, because I now can set any day in `NSDateComponents` like this: `2012-10-119` insteed of `2013-01-26` so it doesn't recalculate date. Of course it is possible to convert `NSDateComponents` to `NSDate` and then convert it back to `NSDateComponents` for recalculating date but I see no advantages in that attitude in these classes.

Comment: Uhm, don't NSDate and NSCalendar "implement[s] Date"? - That is, what *is* the question?

Comment: What are the "very simple tasks" you are trying to achieve? The reason dates are managed the way they are is to support multiple calendars and localization.

Answer (score 4):

You must use NSDate combined with NSDateFormatter. There are tons of examples on stackoverflow.